# skip few lines nd read few lines in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a data file in .txt format, has lines starts with space and lines starts with numeric value. I want to skip all the lines starts with space and read all the lines starts with numeric value and create another .txt file. Looking for your help/suggestions.!

Comment: Suggestion: read the documentation on file I/O.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, to a new user, even looking for the right tutorial could be daunting and overwhelming. To help you with your issue, I wrote down some helpful links below and how I went about finding these links.

[To read text files, take a look at this tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textread.html). I found it by Googling "read text file matlab". The tutorial suggests using the `textread` function to read text files.

[To write text files, take a look at this tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html). I found it by Googling "write text file matlab". The tutorial suggests using the `fprintf` function to write text files.

Hopefully, you now have an idea of how to read and write text files. More importantly, I hope you now have an idea of how to find solutions to a coding problem through online sources. I highly recommend first Googling your problem before relying on any other external sources.